# Hide Rows based on multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My database is getting massive and I am trying to make things a little more manageable. What I am basically trying to do is:

If cell E:E = "Complete" hide the corresponding row
Else If cell F:F = "Complete" hide that same/corresponding Row

This will continue for the 52 weeks of the year, plus an infinite number of Rows depending on the data

I have tried a simple code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(check)

    If Range("E:Z") = Complete Then
        Rows("3:7000").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows("3:7000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
```

This compiles but not a lot else happens.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Observation: Excel is not a database. You should probably migrate your data to a real database.

Comment: @DavidPostill 7000 rows in 52 columns is chicken feed for Excel.

Comment: Would you like to *test current Date with Date on After 52 Weeks to hide rows* or only interest is hide Rows?

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's pick this apart.

Your commands address whole rows and whole columns as blocks, but they don't actually evaluate the current cell. A text value in VBA must be inside double quotes, otherwise Excel will expect this to be a named variable or object.

As far as I understand, you want to look at columns E to Z for the word "Complete" to be entered. The Worksheet_Change event acts on a Target, i.e. the cell that was changed. To see if the cell is in the columns E to Z, you can check if Target intersects with that range.

`Intersect(Target, Range("E:Z"))`

This command returns a range object. If the changed cell is not in the specified range, nothing is returned. So, the next one is a bit of a double negative, but we want things to happen if the intersect object is *not* NOTHING. This writes as follows

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:Z")) Is Nothing Then
'   do something
End If
```

Next you want to check if the value of the target cell is "Complete". It might be a good idea to make this not case sensitive, so wrapping target into a `UCase` will take care of that.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:Z")) Is Nothing Then
    If UCase(Target.Value) = "COMPLETE" Then
        ' some code to hide the row
    End If
End If
```

The code to hide the row needs to get the row number of the target cell. That can be done with `Target.Row`, which can then be fed to the `Rows()` command similar to what you used, but just for the target cell's row.

```
Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

So far the code will be

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:Z")) Is Nothing Then
    If UCase(Target.Value) = "COMPLETE" Then
        Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

... and that will work for individual rows. But if you copy the "Complete" into several rows in one fell swoop, the target will contain more than one rows and the code needs to be adjusted to reflect that. Declare a range named cel and then loop through each cel in the Target range. The UCase and the Rows commands will now need to address `cel` instead of `Target`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cel As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:Z")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cel In Target
        If UCase(cel.Value) = "COMPLETE" Then
            Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cel
End If

End Sub
```

And there you have it.